# all shops in 1 menu opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I'm pretty new to Open cart system, so don't judge too hard on me.

I have a multiple open cart store. Store 1, Store 2, Store 3... and I need to create a dynamic menu which should display in each store:

```
store 1    
  --cat1    
  -----cat2

store 2    
  --cat1    
  -----cat2 

and so on...
```

After hours of googling I'm pretty clueless where to start with. I had an idea of accessing the categories based on the store id's or something like that, but I really don't know if it is possible at all.

If someone had an experience with a task like that I would be really grateful for any tips and suggestions

Comment: do you need to show a list of shops with their links? did you try "Store" module? it is included with opencart installation pack.

Comment: Hi, That's correct, I need all shops with their links. Should it be in the Extentions->modules? If it is so, It is not there... I have OC 2.0.3.1 And it uses Journal theme.

Comment: I've just installed opencart 2.3.0.1 and that module is there, see my answer's screenshot bellow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display a list of multiple stores created under one installation of opencart, there's a built-in module called "Store".

Go to admin panel / extensions / modules / store

[image]

Comment: He thank you very much! I have installation in the other language and in the first place I've searched indeed for STORE, but it is just translated, so it is indeed there.

Comment: You're welcome, If you can't see a module in your language, create a copy of that module's English language file and paste it in your language folder, then you must see it in modules list.

Comment: I have now tested the module "shop". It give's me only the list of all shops, but not the categories under these shops... So this is partly what I want but not completely.